# Angular 2+ key-binding throttle key event

Tags: angular

I have a stack-blitz example here.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jvahcv

What I need is, throttle the arrow key, up/-down key, let's say for 0.5 seconds.
How Can I do this in Angular 2+.

What I not want to do is, subscribe all key events and check if this arrowkey-down or up, can call the dedicated method. Bind the key like this:

```
<div tabindex="-1" (keydown.arrowdown)="logSomething($event)" (keydown.arrowUp)="logSomethingElse($event)">
```

Is more readable code.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Can you provide logSomething($event) and logSomethingElse($event)?

Comment: So, given a keypress every 0.4 seconds, you want to wait 0.5 seconds after the last keypress before running your function? Even if it's a single keypress?

Comment: @KurtHamilton No, Ideally only while holding down, It should wait 0.5 seconds before firing the second time.

Comment: @mamichels I've updated the stack-blitz link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Your problem

You want to:

- Call a function for a key press
- Limit function calls to one per second

#### My design

I would use observables for this. The pattern would be:

- Create proxy `Subject` for `keydown` events
- Expose proxy `Subject` as `Observable` with `throttleTime` operator
- Call function from proxy `Observable` subscription

### My implementation

Create a class to wrap the subject. It will have a simple interface:

- `keyDown$: Observable<any>` - the proxy `Observable`
- `keyDown()` - called on every `keydown` event
- `complete()` - called on destroy

```js
export class KeyThrottle {   

  constructor(duration: number) {
    this.keyDown$ = this._keyDown$.pipe(
      throttleTime(duration)
    );
  }

  keyDown$: Observable<any>;

  private _keyDown$ = new Subject();

  complete(): void {
    this._keyDown$.complete();
  }

  keyDown(): void {
    this._keyDown$.next();
  }
}
```

You would create a new instance for each key that you wanted to handle in your component:

```js
private throttles = {
  arrowDown: new KeyThrottle(1000),
  arrowUp: new KeyThrottle(1000)
};

ngOnInit() {
  this.throttles.arrowDown.keyDown$.subscribe(() => {
    this.logSomething();
  });

  this.throttles.arrowUp.keyDown$.subscribe(() => {
    this.logSomethingElse();
  });
}

ngOnDestroy() {
  this.throttles.arrowDown.complete();
  this.throttles.arrowUp.complete();
}

private logSomething() {
  console.log('key down pressed');
}

private logSomethingElse() {
  console.log('key up pressed');
}
```

Your HTML has an event handler per key that you want to handle.

```html
<div tabindex="-1" 
  (keydown.arrowdown)="throttles.arrowDown.keyDown()"  
  (keydown.arrowup)="throttles.arrowUp.keyDown()">
  <p>
    Open the console. Click here. Press and hold (Arrow-Up/Down).
  </p>
</div>
```

DEMO: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tj2ajr

Comment: No, this is not what I'm looking for. I want to throttle by 1 Console.Log per second instead of 0.4.

Comment: I've redone my answer so that key presses are throttled to one per second while a key is held down.